# Having trouble retrieving text using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble retrieving the text of an HTML element.

```js
var text_element = document.getElementById("details").getElementsByTagName("h3");
var text = text_element.innerText;
console.log(text_element);
console.log(text);
```

```html
<div id="details">
  <h3>Summary for</h3>
</div>
```

When I make the console call for `text_element`, I can actually see the `h3`object info, but when I call `text` I get `undefined`.

If I change the JS to be `var text = text_element.innerHTML;` I get the same,  `undefined`.

Shouldn't I be getting the text inside the `h3` element, **Summary for** instead of `undefined`?

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and what I need to do to fix it?

I am not using jQuery, this is strictly pure Javascript.

Comment: `getElement S ByTagName` so you should write `getElementsByTagName("h3")[0]`

Comment: `gEBTagName` returns an ARRAY of matched elements...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `.getElementsByTagName("h3")` returns a NodeList (Or an HTMLCollection, now, in Firefox), not an Element, and NodeList prototype does not have a `innerText` property.

You can get the first element of the node list with its index:

```js
var text_elements = document.getElementById("details").getElementsByTagName("h3");
var text = text_elements[0].innerText;
console.log(text_elements[0]);
console.log(text);
```

```html
<div id="details">
  <h3>Summary for</h3>
</div>
```

Beware: NodeList and HTMLCollection objects are not `Array`s, even though they are array-like objects (like `arguments`). [You can read more about Array-like objects](http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/06/advanced-javascript-objects-arrays-and-array-like-objects/).

Answer (score 0):

Here you are, faster:

```js
alert(document.querySelector('h3').innerText);
```

```html
<div id="details">
  <h3>Summary for</h3>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach:1** Accessing by `id`

```
var text_element = document.getElementById("details");
var text = text_element.innerText;
console.log(text_element);
console.log(text);
```

**Approach:2** Accessing by `getElementsByTagName("h3")`.

```
var text_elements = document.getElementById("details").getElementsByTagName("h3");
var text = text_elements[0].innerText;
console.log(text_elements[0]);
console.log(text);
```

[MDN - Element.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)

> The Element.getElementsByTagName() method returns a live HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name. The subtree underneath the specified element is searched, excluding the element itself. The returned list is live, meaning that it updates itself with the DOM tree automatically. Consequently, there is no need to call several times Element.getElementsByTagName() with the same element and arguments.

Comment: No, it is _not_ an array of element, but a `NodeList`, or an `HTMLCollection`, that are both array-like objects, but not `Array`s

Answer (score 0):

When you get a text/content of tag by this method "getElementsByTagName()" - then it returns a collection of an elements's child elements with the specified tag name or can say collection of HTML and you can get by giving index.

Example.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("h3"); - [<h3> Summary For </h3>]
document.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0]; - [<h3> Summary For </h3>]
document.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0].innerHTML; - Summary For
```

In your example

```
var text_element = document.getElementById("details").getElementsByTagName("h3")[0];
var text = text_element.innerHTML;    
alert(text); // Summary For
```